# FullCalendar: Load events on start from hibernate tables

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, jsp, fullcalendar

Im trying to load events which are stored in database. 
I was reading decumentation on arshaw's FullCalendar site but without success.
Here you can see my user-details site where you can see table with events

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>    
            <th>Start Date</th> 
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${user.events}" var="events">
        <tr>
            <td>${events.name}</td>
            <td>${events.description}</td>
            <td>${events.startDate}</td>
            <td>${events.endDate}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my InitDatabaseService there is one event stored:

```
Events eventNr1 = new Events();
    eventNr1.setName("sometitle");
    eventNr1.setUser(userAdmin);
    eventNr1.setStartDate("2014, 07, 25");
    eventNr1.setEndDate("2014, 07, 26");
    eventNr1.setDescriptionField("texttexttexttext");
    eventsRepository.save(eventNr1);
```

This is working well. But i don't know how to add this event to calendar instead of table. 
This is my fullCalendar script in schedule.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {


            /* initialize the calendar
             -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev next',
                    center: 'title,today',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {//This is to add icons to the visible buttons
                    prev: "<span class='fa fa-caret-left'></span>",
                    next: "<span class='fa fa-caret-right'></span>",
                    today: 'today',
                    month: 'month',
                    week: 'week',
                    day: 'day'
                },
                aspectRatio: 2,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 

                    var title = prompt('Event Titlesss:');
                    if (title) {

                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            },
                            true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },

                editable: true,
                theme: false,
                //Random default events


                events: [
                   // <c:forEach items="${user.events}" var="events">
                    //title: '${events.name}',
                    //start: new Date('${events.startDate}'),
                    //backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
                    //borderColor: "#f56954"//red






                    {
                        title: "All Day Event",
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
                        borderColor: "#f56954" //red
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Long Event",
                        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                        backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
                        borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
                        borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
                        borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
                        borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
                        borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
                    }
                  //  </c:forEach> 
                ],


            });


        });
    </script>
```

I've tried to use foreach to add all this events but wothout success.

So how can I do this? :)

Comment: can use server url to pass events , plugin will make ajax call to retrieve them. See docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventSources propertie and provide it with your custom url server to fill the events using json feed

You can find more info about json feed in the official documentation:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/